# Function sum that is both pointwise and uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f_n : [a, b] \to \mathbb R$ be a sequence of functions that converges uniformly to 0. Also, suppose that, for each $x \in [a, b]$, the sequence $\{|f_n(x)|\}$ is monotonically decreasing, and that $f_n(x) \leq 0$ for even $n$ and $f_n(x) \geq 0$ for odd $n$. Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ is both pointwise and uniformly convergent.

This is my approach. Let $x \in [a,b]$ be arbitrary. Since $f_n \to 0$ uniformly on $[a,b]$, there exists an $N$ such that $∣f_n(x)| < \frac12$ for all $n > N$.

Since $∣f_n(x)∣$ is monotonically decreasing, we have $∣f_n(x)∣≤∣f_k(x)∣$ for all $n \geq k > N$. Therefore, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^N f_n(x) + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty f_n(x)\\
&\leq \sum_{n=1}^N f_n(x) + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty |f_n(x)|\\
&\leq \sum_{n=1}^N f_n(x) + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac12\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^N f_n(x) + \frac N2.
\end{align}

Since the sum $\sum_{n=1}^N f_n(x)$ is a finite sum of continuous functions, it is continuous. Therefore the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ is continuous and hence pointwise convergent.

However, I am not sure this solution is correct, and I'm not quite sure how to work the uniform convergence case. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake has been highlighted in the previous answer. Also, the hint for proving point-wise convergence (Leibnitz's alternating test) has been suggested in the previous answer. For the uniform convergence part, we can, hopefully, argue as follows. Before that, fix
$$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}f_n(x) = S_k(x).$$
For the $\epsilon>0$, fix $N$ such that for all $x\in[a,b]$ and for all $n\geq N$, we have
$$|f_n(x)| < \epsilon \tag{1}$$
This is possible as $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $[a,b]$. Let $m$ be an odd integer greater than or equal to $N$. Then, it is easy to see that
$$0\leq \sum\limits_{k=m}^{\infty}f_k(x) \leq f_m(x) \tag{2}$$
This is because, we can easily observe based on the facts $\{|f_n(x)|\}$ is monotonically decreasing, $f_n(x)\leq0$ for even $n$ and $f_n(x)\geq0$ for odd $n$ that
$$\sum\limits_{k=m}^{\infty}f_k(x)\geq 0 \quad \text{whenever $m$ is odd} $$
and
$$\sum\limits_{k=m^{\prime}}^{\infty}f_k(x)\leq 0,\quad \text{whenever $m^{\prime}$ is even}.$$
Thus, from $(2)$, it follows that
$$\begin{vmatrix}\sum\limits_{k=m}^{\infty}f_k(x)\end{vmatrix}= \sum\limits_{k=m}^{\infty}f_k(x) \leq f_m(x) =|f_m(x)| <\epsilon, $$
for all $x$ as per our assumption $(1)$ as $m$ is chosen to be greater than or equal to $N$. Thus, we just showed that for all odd $m\geq N$, we have
$$\begin{vmatrix}\sum\limits_{k=m}^{\infty}f_k(x)\end{vmatrix} < \epsilon,$$
for all $x\in [a,b]$.

Now, if $m$ is even, then again by the given assumptions, we have
$$0\leq -\sum\limits_{k=m}^{\infty}f_k(x) \leq -f_m.$$
(Note that $f_m \leq 0$ when $m$ is even). In other words, we are suggesting that
$$0\leq \begin{vmatrix}\sum\limits_{k=m}^{\infty}f_k(x)\end{vmatrix} \leq |f_m(x)|.$$

Thus, again by $(1)$, we have
$$\begin{vmatrix}\sum\limits_{k=m}^{\infty}f_k(x)\end{vmatrix} < \epsilon, \tag{3}$$
for all $x\in [a,b]$. Thus, we showed that for all even $m\geq N$, $(3)$ holds. What did we prove? Simply that for all $m\geq N$ and for all $x\in [a,b]$, the following holds:
$$\begin{vmatrix}\sum\limits_{k=m}^{\infty}f_k(x)\end{vmatrix}<\epsilon.$$

This proves that the convergence of the series of functions is uniform as the chosen $\epsilon$ was arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment yet, I'll post an answer. This looks incorrect as is. Are you making the mistake that $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty 1/2 \leq N/2$ ?

Hint for pointwise convergence : show that if $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ is an alternating sequence (ie. for all $n\geq 0$, $a_na_{n+1} \leq 0$) and $(|a_n|)_{n=0 }^\infty$ is nonincreasing and converges to 0, then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges.

Comment: I tried this, but I am still stuck. Could you help me with why doing this is useful?